# Configuring Session for load-balancer

Tags: session-state, load-balancer

In one of our Sitecore application we have only enabled Sitecore XP  and disabled the Sitecore XDB.

We are using the sessions in our application(to store and pass the values to 3rd party services).This application will be hosted in the load balancing environment(with 2 CD).

In such scenario, can we use sticky session? Or is there any other method to configure session in loadbalancer

Answer (score 2):

In this situation you must:

- use In process session state *with sticky sessions* on the loadbalancer
- use an Out of process solution (SQL Server / MongoDB / Redis)

I suggest to read this documentation page of Sitecore: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/session_state/session_state

Comment: lol, You duplicated my answer, but got more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Use sticky session. In this case load balancer will route user to certain CD server(to server, where he was previously).
2. Use session state provider that allow sharing session between environments. It could be: [ASP.Net SQL Server session provider](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/317604/how-to-configure-sql-server-to-store-asp-net-session-state), [CouchBase session provider](https://blog.couchbase.com/introducing-couchbase-aspnet-sessionstate-provider/), [MongoDB ASP.NET Session State Store Provider](https://mongosessionstate.codeplex.com/), etc. In this case, you don't need to use sticky session.